# unable to connect my mern application with heroku dont know where is wrong some one please help me with that

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mern

Application error:
[image]

i got some error in my logs

```js
$ heroku logs --tail
2022-07-05T06:39:38.508197+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:1)
2022-07-05T06:39:38.508197+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)     
2022-07-05T06:40:37.239154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-05T06:40:37.271175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-05T06:40:37.411800+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-05T06:40:37.513052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-05T06:40:37.516497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-05T06:40:42.264977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-05T06:40:43.980138+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-05T06:40:43.980156+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-07-05T06:40:43.980157+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./index.js
2022-07-05T06:40:43.980157+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-05T06:40:44.419275+00:00 app[web.1]: Example app listening on port http://localhost:5500
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421393+00:00 app[web.1]: Error connecting to Mongo MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421394+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:689:11)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421395+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:377:10
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421396+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421396+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421397+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421397+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1220:10)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421397+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:376:20)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421398+00:00 app[web.1]: at connectToMongo (/app/db.js:6:5)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421398+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:1)
2022-07-05T06:40:44.421399+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)     
2022-07-05T06:41:42.489735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-05T06:41:42.555839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-05T06:41:42.704973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-05T06:41:42.764933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-05T06:41:45.708056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=45b0e488-1081-49a4-babc-8ac017b331b4 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T06:41:46.719799+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=fa63469e-84d5-4e26-b9e9-b26c603ae18c fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T06:55:51.468435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=7b3fb9c9-2a8c-4cdd-aa5b-14782ffe13bf fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T06:55:51.800574+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=08ca31ae-bda1-4858-85f7-9e2450d5e982 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:03:38.953758+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user codewithmufaddal@gmail.com
2022-07-05T07:03:38.953758+00:00 app[api]: Set MONGO_URL config vars by user codewithmufaddal@gmail.com        
2022-07-05T07:03:40.004416+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-05T07:03:44.517238+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-05T07:03:45.966051+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-05T07:03:45.966065+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-07-05T07:03:45.966065+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./index.js
2022-07-05T07:03:45.966065+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-05T07:03:46.381818+00:00 app[web.1]: Example app listening on port http://localhost:5500
2022-07-05T07:03:48.206096+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to Mongo!
2022-07-05T07:04:45.309294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-05T07:04:45.357684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-05T07:04:45.492305+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-05T07:04:46.095212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-05T07:04:46.099519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-05T07:04:50.504015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-05T07:04:51.598705+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-05T07:04:51.598715+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-07-05T07:04:51.598715+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./index.js
2022-07-05T07:04:51.598716+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-05T07:04:52.013745+00:00 app[web.1]: Example app listening on port http://localhost:5500
2022-07-05T07:04:53.827531+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to Mongo!
2022-07-05T07:05:51.110034+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-05T07:05:51.232487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-05T07:05:51.360233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-05T07:05:51.437811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-05T07:05:52.122029+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=aba6040c-520d-42b0-9b90-93e7c01441cf fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:05:52.873963+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=ee144b15-ffd9-42ca-a0c8-2754879ea951 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:06:02.753165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=fd6b5acd-cc50-4290-8705-a182caa73690 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:06:03.040453+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=279426f8-5edc-4901-a43c-5402a236d2d3 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:06:06.108553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=8bdae580-3616-40e3-8500-cb5f15802a36 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:06:06.415087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=6e684264-ab14-4b30-9690-115142e24acf fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:06:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user codewithmufaddal@gmail.com
2022-07-05T07:07:28.909507+00:00 app[api]: Release v10 created by user codewithmufaddal@gmail.com
2022-07-05T07:07:28.909507+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ae3db0ed by user codewithmufaddal@gmail.com
2022-07-05T07:07:29.171028+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-05T07:07:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-07-05T07:07:37.798655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-07-05T07:07:39.655884+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-05T07:07:39.655895+00:00 app[web.1]: > backend@1.0.0 start
2022-07-05T07:07:39.655895+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./index.js
2022-07-05T07:07:39.655895+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-05T07:07:40.065691+00:00 app[web.1]: Example app listening on port http://localhost:5500
2022-07-05T07:07:41.879078+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to Mongo!
2022-07-05T07:08:38.079247+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-07-05T07:08:38.108595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-07-05T07:08:38.259120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-07-05T07:08:38.328162+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-05T07:08:39.465785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=35b77c9d-45bb-489a-9541-e3da1b8ce6d2 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:08:39.741530+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=9a8e7998-1847-48ff-af83-dc0a71c0b13c fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:08:45.430719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=09c09ca8-459d-42c2-bf41-01cb6b4e2827 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:08:45.758903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=d646a0a3-24bd-49a6-9f24-ee15d908fe3b fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:09:16.734801+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=a810fe99-c12a-4bfd-9cd2-02f013b658a5 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:09:17.039258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=fde5c406-02a2-4fd9-90f9-5cd3921e8d95 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:10:43.261020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=a6ca50a7-a807-4d2b-a05a-557f01261720 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:10:43.531049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=93f8bb08-4eb4-4810-9bb0-d7ea3e00c866 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:11:01.599882+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=65e9a7b9-79f0-43b2-bb32-75fe3615aee7 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:11:02.006301+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=dc4780f7-b52b-45cd-ac7b-43d7b2086a6b fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:12:45.784622+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=082b677d-1e71-40d5-b5c1-959f1ffdfc23 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:12:46.095569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=76e8886d-e511-4653-9ded-42714dad3675 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:17:39.116659+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=97baf221-e000-4a13-ab50-9eee526381bf fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:17:39.505369+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=5518dda5-6035-420d-9080-097696d04500 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:18:15.091809+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=4ef261d1-5677-4396-83ef-cb076ff8d705 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:18:15.412354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=1d185b99-03fc-49b7-bd31-af5e8777c4fb fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:19:19.772384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=b03e47c4-bdd4-41a9-8c86-40863a926057 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:19:20.181880+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=3172da8d-4891-4698-b27f-dbdf4ac173dd fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:23:40.514920+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=adddf84e-c523-489b-9c8d-8ec3111ecf00 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-05T07:23:40.828730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hatsoffdigital-career.herokuapp.com request_id=e4305bf2-fef1-4c2f-8498-50dc64855199 fwd="103.132.29.188" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

i am unable to understand that please help me with that ,
my code is running perfectly with localhost everything is fine but with heroku i dont know whats a problem

i have use mongo url also added in heroku confige var but still did't work
i am unable to understand that please help me with that ,
my code is running perfectly with localhost everything is fine but with heroku i dont know whats a problem

i have use mongo url also added in heroku confige var but still did't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your app is listening on the wrong port. You need to use `process.env.PORT` as the port to listen on. But your app shows it's listening on port 5500:

```
Example app listening on port http://localhost:5500
```

If you post your `index.js` or a link to a GitHub repo, I can give you more specific advice on fixing it.